# Binding treeview dynamically using datarelation and xml

Tags: c#, xml

```
DataRelation rel = new DataRelation("ClientCategory", dtTree.Tables[0].Columns["TPAClientGroupId"], dtTree.Tables[1].Columns["TPAClientGroupId"], true);
rel.Nested = true;

dtTree.Relations.Add(rel);

XmlDataSource xmlD = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource();
xmlD.ID = "clientGroupsxml";
xmlD.Data = dtTree.GetXml(); 

TreeView1.DataSource = xmlD;
TreeView1.DataBind();
```

Am using this code to bind Treeview ..but its not working....

Comment: Can you post your XML?  As well as the structure of dtTree.Tables[0]?

Comment: NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <TPAClientGroupId>1</TPAClientGroupId>
    <TPAClientGroupName>Yum! Brands</TPAClientGroupName>
    <Table1>
      <TPAClientGroupId>1</TPAClientGroupId>
      <TPAClientId>420</TPAClientId>
      <TPAClientNumber>001966</TPAClientNumber>
      <TPAClientName>LONG JOHN SILVER'S, INC.</TPAClientName>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
      <TPAClientGroupId>1</TPAClientGroupId>
      <TPAClientId>421</TPAClientId>
      <TPAClientNumber>001967</TPAClientNumber>
      <TPAClientName>A &amp; W RESTAURANTS</TPAClientName>
    </Table1>

Comment: @shijuse, you need to edit your question and add the XML there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data column mapping to attribute

```
DataRelation rel = new DataRelation("ClientCategory", dtTree.Tables[0].Columns["TPAClientGroupId"], dtTree.Tables[1].Columns["TPAClientGroupId"], true);
rel.Nested = true;

dtTree.Relations.Add(rel);


foreach (DataColumn dc in dst.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
}
foreach (DataColumn dc in dst.Tables[1].Columns)
{
    dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
}

XmlDataSource xmlD = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource();
xmlD.ID = "clientGroupsxml";
xmlD.Data = dtTree.GetXml();
```